# Pyspark : How to split pipe-separated column into multiple rows?

Tags: pyspark, explode

I have a dataframe that contains the following:

```
movieId / movieName / genre
1         example1    action|thriller|romance
2         example2    fantastic|action
```

I would like to obtain a second dataframe (from the first one), that contains the following:

```
movieId / movieName / genre
1         example1    action
1         example1    thriller
1         example1    romance
2         example2    fantastic
2         example2    action
```

How can we do it using pyspark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **`split`** function will return an `array` then `explode` function on array.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show(10,False)
#+-------+---------+-----------------------+
#|movieid|moviename|genre                  |
#+-------+---------+-----------------------+
#|1      |example1 |action|thriller|romance|
#+-------+---------+-----------------------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumnRenamed("genre","genre1").\
withColumn("genre",explode(split(col("genre1"),'\\|'))).\
drop("genre1").\
show()
#+-------+---------+--------+
#|movieid|moviename|   genre|
#+-------+---------+--------+
#|      1| example1|  action|
#|      1| example1|thriller|
#|      1| example1| romance|
#+-------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks. This works too.            
df.withColumn("genre",explode(split(col("genre"),'\\|'))).show()                                                     any reason you added genre1 column and then dropped it?